# Excel VBA add image to Word doc and convert to shape

Tags: excel, vba

I am adding an image using a URL to a Word doc template. I need to convert the inline shape to a shape so that I can change the wrapping and position. My code is as follows:

```
Sub AddImg()

Dim objWord
Dim Template As String
Dim Img As InlineShape
Dim Shp As Shape

'Get Word template
Template = "..examplePath\Template.docx"
Set objWord = CreateObject("word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

'Copy template
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(Template:=Template, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

'Get image by URL
objWord.Application.Selection.Find.Execute "{Image}"
Set Img = objWord.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(Filename:="www.example.com/example.png", _
    LinkToFile:=False, _
    SaveWithDocument:=True)
Set Shp = Img.ConvertToShape
With Shp
    .LockAspectRatio = True
    .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare
    .Width = CentimetersToPoints(4)
End With

End Sub
```

It works correctly but line `Set Shp = Img.ConvertToShape` is throwing error "Type mismatch". Why  am I struggling to `Set Shp` correctly?

Comment: Your code is correct (that code line, I mean...). Are you sure that the picture is added to the document? Please, place the next debugging line before the `problematic` one: `Debug.print TypeName(Shp): Stop`. What can you see in `Immediate Window` when code stops on this line? Does it return `InlineShape` or does it raise an error?

Comment: @FaneDuru the picture is added to the document and it does seem like it is also converted to a shape because it is changed to sit above the text. The Immediate window prints "Nothing". `Debug.Print TypeName(Img): Stop` prints "InlineShape"

Answer (score 0):

I had to change `Dim Shp As Shape` to `Dim Shp As Object`